# Highcharts having problems with Ajax Request

Tags: jquery, ajax, highcharts

I want to display a series in a highcharts graph. The data should come from my db (ajax request). The query takes around 7-8 seconds until I get a response and I guess that this might be the problem.

If I use the exact same ajax response as plain data I can see the Chart as intended. If I use the direct response variable (data) it won't work and doesn't show the graph. The plain data is 100% the same as the ajax response is (I copied the console.log). I have no idea why this is happening.

This works:

```
function loadBotStatistics(){
    $("#loadingImage").show();

    $.post( "ajax_load_bot_statistics.php", function (data){
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'line'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Logins from unique Members'
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'line',
                name: 'Logins',
                data: [{"y":31713,"0":31713,"x":1456379177000,"1":1456379177000,"session_end":"2016-02-25 06:46:17","2":"2016-02-25 06:46:17"},{"y":31474,"0":31474,"x":1456452049000,"1":1456452049000,"session_end":"2016-02-26 03:00:49","2":"2016-02-26 03:00:49"},{"y":29099,"0":29099,"x":1456558947000,"1":1456558947000,"session_end":"2016-02-27 08:42:27","2":"2016-02-27 08:42:27"},{"y":28108,"0":28108,"x":1456674895000,"1":1456674895000,"session_end":"2016-02-28 16:54:55","2":"2016-02-28 16:54:55"},{"y":31365,"0":31365,"x":1456704987000,"1":1456704987000,"session_end":"2016-02-29 01:16:27","2":"2016-02-29 01:16:27"},{"y":31201,"0":31201,"x":1456858522000,"1":1456858522000,"session_end":"2016-03-01 19:55:22","2":"2016-03-01 19:55:22"},{"y":30999,"0":30999,"x":1456906468000,"1":1456906468000,"session_end":"2016-03-02 09:14:28","2":"2016-03-02 09:14:28"},{"y":31630,"0":31630,"x":1456960648000,"1":1456960648000,"session_end":"2016-03-03 00:17:28","2":"2016-03-03 00:17:28"},{"y":29508,"0":29508,"x":1457069814000,"1":1457069814000,"session_end":"2016-03-04 06:36:54","2":"2016-03-04 06:36:54"},{"y":28399,"0":28399,"x":1457143229000,"1":1457143229000,"session_end":"2016-03-05 03:00:29","2":"2016-03-05 03:00:29"},{"y":29520,"0":29520,"x":1457273151000,"1":1457273151000,"session_end":"2016-03-06 15:05:51","2":"2016-03-06 15:05:51"},{"y":28447,"0":28447,"x":1457321588000,"1":1457321588000,"session_end":"2016-03-07 04:33:08","2":"2016-03-07 04:33:08"},{"y":29396,"0":29396,"x":1457393708000,"1":1457393708000,"session_end":"2016-03-08 00:35:08","2":"2016-03-08 00:35:08"},{"y":31021,"0":31021,"x":1457533934000,"1":1457533934000,"session_end":"2016-03-09 15:32:14","2":"2016-03-09 15:32:14"}]
            }]
        });
        console.log(data);
        $("#loadingImage").hide();
    });

}
```

This doesn't work (empty graph):

```
function loadBotStatistics(){
    $("#loadingImage").show();

    $.post( "ajax_load_bot_statistics.php", function (data){
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'line'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Logins from unique Members'
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'line',
                name: 'Logins',
                data: data
                }]
        });
        console.log(data);
        $("#loadingImage").hide();
    });

}
```

Why does it not work once I use the data variable instead of the same response hardcoded?

Comment: Try to add $('#container').highcharts().redraw()

Comment: Just tried it, but still the same issue.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? Also could you post the exact response from the AJAX call, because that seems to be the only possible problem.

Comment: Rahul as stated in my post the original and EXACT response from the Ajax call is being used in my first code paste (and it works there). I copied it from the console.log. The data attribute should be 1:1 the same.

Comment: Replace the line $.post( "ajax_load_bot_statistics.php", function (data){
        $('#container').highcharts({ with $.post( "ajax_load_bot_statistics.php", function (data){
console.log(data);
        $('#container').highcharts({

Run your console (developer tools in the Chrome), and let me know if any errors appers and what is in response.

Comment: @SebastianBochan this is the output: http://i.imgur.com/DosRsWd.png . If I use exactly this output as data field it will work (as described in the original topic).

Comment: In the console you have the [#12](http://www.highcharts.com/errors/12) error from Highcharts, which is the reason of unworking demo.

Comment: @SebastianBochan I saw that, but it doesn't make sense for me, because if I use the same output coming as response it will work without error. Furthermore error #12 says the number of points exceeds the turboThreshold which doesn't make sense for me either.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
function loadBotStatistics(){
    $("#loadingImage").show();
    $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'line'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Logins from unique Members'
            }
        });
    $.post( "ajax_load_bot_statistics.php", function (data){
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        if (chart.series.length === 1) {
            chart.addSeries({
                type: 'line',
                name: 'Logins',                    
                data: data
            });
        }
        $("#loadingImage").hide();
    });

}
```

Comment: Also empty, this time even without axis.